# Compare all lines in a file

Tags: perl

I have a file contains this text:

```
perl java python php scala
java pascal perl ruby ada 
ASP awk php java perl
C# ada python java scala
```

I would like to compare each two line and display the number of shared word, I wrote a program who display the shared number of word between the first line and the others lines, first line and second line contain 2 (perl, java) common word, first and third have 3 words, and first and fourth have 3 words.
But I would like to compare also the second line with first, the third and the fourth, the same for the third line, and so on. 
This is my code:

```
open(F,"/home/Bureau/test2/terms.txt")||die " Pb pour ouvrir";
my $firstLine = <F>;

my @a =split(/ /, $firstLine);
while (<F>) {

my @b = split(/ /,$_ );

my @intersection =
    grep { defined }
        @{ { map { lc ,=> $_ } @a } }
           { map { lc } @b };
print $#intersection."\n";
}
```

I think that the problem is how to change the contents of @a with the next line, I tried but I didn't arrive at a solution, 
Thanks for all.

Comment: You have received three comprehensive answers, and you wrote in a comment that your problem has been solved. May I ask you to please select the solution that you think best answers your question and accept it by clicking the check mark next to it? That will mark your question as being resolved, and people will no longer come here thinking that you still need help.

Comment: it's done, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution builds an array of hashes corresponding to the lines of the array. Then two nested loops use `grep` to count the number of words that occur both in any given hash and all following ones

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    push @data, { map { $_ => 1 } split };
}

for my $i ( 0 .. $#data-1 ) {

    for my $j ( $i + 1 .. $#data ) {

        my $join = grep { $data[$i]{$_} } keys %{ $data[$j] };

        printf "Line %s has %d word%s in common with line %d\n",
            $i + 1,
            $join,
            $join == 1 ? '' : 's',
            $j + 1;        }
}



__DATA__
perl java python php scala
java pascal perl ruby ada 
ASP awk php java perl
C# ada python java scala
```

#### output

```
Line 1 has 2 words in common with line 2
Line 1 has 3 words in common with line 3
Line 1 has 3 words in common with line 4
Line 2 has 2 words in common with line 3
Line 2 has 2 words in common with line 4
Line 3 has 1 word in common with line 4
```

Comment: Thanks Bodorin, but have you any idea to compare also line 2 with line 1, 3 and 4, and compare line 3 with line 1, 2, and 4, and so on ?

Comment: @Ahmed: All possible pairs of lines have been compared.  Comparing line 2 with line 1 is the same as comparing line 1 with line 2 -- the output says that there are 2 words in common. The same applies to all the other pairs you think are missing.

Answer (score 3):

> But I would like to compare also the second line with first, the third and the
>   fourth, the same for the third line

My suggestion would be to create a proper data structure which contains line number and the words in it. So that it's easy to compare any line with another line. For example see below:

```
use warnings;
use strict;    
use Data::Dumper;

my %lines;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @words_in_line = split /\s/, $_;
    $lines{$.} = \@words_in_line;
}
print Dumper \%lines;

__DATA__
perl java python php scala
java pascal perl ruby ada 
ASP awk php java perl
C# ada python java scala
```

This gives below structure which you can easily work upon to get desired data:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => [
                   'C#',
                   'ada',
                   'python',
                   'java',
                   'scala'
                 ],
          '3' => [
                   'ASP',
                   'awk',
                   'php',
                   'java',
                   'perl'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   'java',
                   'pascal',
                   'perl',
                   'ruby',
                   'ada'
                 ],
          '1' => [
                   'perl',
                   'java',
                   'python',
                   'php',
                   'scala'
                 ]
        };
```

**Example:** Compare first line with third line

```
my @words_in_first_line = @{$lines{'1'}};
my @words_in_third_line = @{$lines{'3'}};

my @intersection = List::Compare->new(\@words_in_first_line, \@words_in_third_line)->get_intersection;
print @intersection;
```

This looks flexible to me, rather than doing everything in loop and handling previous/current/next line which is too restrictive.

Comment: This would be a more rational way of approaching it *if* you are looking to do more than just one comparision.

Comment: Thanks chankey ; it work , but i tried to automatically pass to the next line but no result  for (my $i=2; $i<5;$i++){ my @words_in_third_line = @{$lines{'$i'}};}   this not work this the error i have : Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ./wordCount.pl line 79, <F> line 4.

Comment: @Ahmed: You have used `$i` inside single quote which is non-interpolable. Use it with double quotes. `"$i"`.

Answer (score 1):

Combining [Chankey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257635/chankey-pathak) and my answers, gives the below solution.

First build an array of hashes, which represents each of the lines (the first `while` loop, based on Chankey's answer).

We then step through each element of the array with a `foreach`. We then  create a `splice` of the other elements minus the present "line" we are processing which ends up in `@others`. Then we compare the "present line" `$lines[$count]` hash with `grep` against the other lines inside `@others` using `map` (where each element of `@others` is set in `$_` during the `map`).

The result for each of these comparsions is put inside an array reference (the square brackets around the `grep`) and all comparisions foreach line are stored inside `%results`;

```
use warnings;
use strict;    
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @lines;
while(<DATA>) {
    push @lines, { map { $_ => 1 } split };
}

my %results;
my $count=0;
foreach(@lines) {
    say 'Comparing Line ' . ($count+1) . ' with other lines';

    my @others = @lines;
    splice @others, $count, 1;
    # this is the same as my first answer, but doing so for
    # each line via map()
    @{ $results{$count+1} } = map {
        [ grep { exists ${$lines[$count]}{$_} } keys %{ $_ } ]
    } @others;

    $count++;
}

print Dumper(\%results);
__DATA__
perl java python php scala
java pascal perl ruby ada 
ASP awk php java perl
C# ada python java scala
```

Give the outputs

```
$VAR1 = {
      '4' => [
               [
                 'python',
                 'java',
                 'scala'
               ],
               [
                 'ada',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'java'
               ]
             ],
      '1' => [
               [
                 'perl',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'perl',
                 'php',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'python',
                 'java',
                 'scala'
               ]
             ],
      '3' => [
               [
                 'php',
                 'perl',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'perl',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'java'
               ]
             ],
      '2' => [
               [
                 'perl',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'perl',
                 'java'
               ],
               [
                 'ada',
                 'java'
               ]
             ]
    };
```

Just to break down the more complex part:

The `map` is iterating `@others`, which is an array of hashes.
Each element corresponding to the "other lines" we are matching against.

For each iteration of `map` we get each element of `@others` inside
`$_`. This is each of the lines we are comparing against. We then get the keys of that specific array element ("the words of that line") via:

```
    keys %{ $_ }
```

Next we pass these words to `grep { }`, and it receives them in it's own `$_` (one for each word). So at this point we are stepping through each word of "another line", and seeing if it `exists` in our present line `$lines[$count]`:

```
    exists ${ $lines[$count] }{$_}
```

The words of our "present line" `${ $lines[$count] }`, with key `$_` (the word on the "other line" we're trying to match).

`grep` returns all the matched words of the present line vs the line being compared, and `map` does this for all lines inside `@others`.

Finally each comparision's results, inside the `map()`, will return an array of arrays, which will be stored in the results hash with the key `$count+1` (the line number being compared to).

```
    @{ $results{$count+1} } =  map { ... }
```

Comment: Minor style point - I'd probably suggest using `or die` rather than `|| die` - the reason being that with parenthesis it's irrelevant, but you can write `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$!"` and it'll work properly, where with `||` it won't. I  would however, also suggest a 3 arg open.

Comment: Will do, I was already correcting the 3rd argument `open()` as we speak (as well as a programmatical error) :)

Comment: Thank Drav for your help, but this don't give for exemple the common words between line 2 and line one, three and four for example, just the line one and the others.

Comment: @ahmed I typo'ed, I forgot the `%previous = %present;` it should work fine now :)

Comment: same problem :( this is the result i have $VAR1 = [
          'perl',
          'java'
        ];
-----------------------------------------
$VAR1 = [
          'perl',
          'java'
        ];
-----------------------------------------
$VAR1 = [
          'java'
        ];
-----------------------------------------

Comment: Aaah you want to compare each line to the other three? (rather than 1st with 2nd, 2nd with 3rd, 3rd with 4th) which is what I'm doing?

Comment: yes this is the result i want, the first line with the others, the seconde line with the first, the third and the fourth line, the third line with the first, the seconde and last line and so on

Comment: my $file= '/home/ahmed/Bureau/test2/test5/terms.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$!";

my %previous;
while(<$fh>) {
    my %present;

    if(!%previous) {
        %previous = map { lc($_) => 1 } split;
        next;
    } else {
        %present = map { lc($_) => 1 } split;
    }

    my @intersection = grep { exists $present{$_} } keys %previous;

    print Dumper(\@intersection);
    print "-----------------------------------------\n";

    %previous = %present;
} i taped your code, the result like i told you,

Comment: @ahmed combined mine and [Chankey's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/257635/chankey-pathak) answers to give the solution you were looking for.

Comment: Ok Drav, i still look at all the solutions to find the best one, i will indicate it when i finish, thanks for your help really :)

Comment: This seem the best solution :) but just a small problem, REALLY i'm sorry, just i would the display like this Line 1 has 2 words in common with line 2 Line 1 has 3 words in common with line 3 Line 1 has 3 words in common with line 4, Line 2 has 2 words in common with line 1 Line 2 has 2 words in common with line 3 Line 1 has 2 words in common with line 4,and so on ... and just extract from each line the first word, i didn't arrive at it, or how to transform the result in simple array to facilitate the read